# NodeJs manage socket.io clients

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm looking for a way to handle the socket.io connections on my nodeJs server.

Calling once `socket.connect('server-addr')` of a client, makes the socket.io server save, each time the client connects, a new reference in `io.sockets.clients()`. It doesn't check if the client is already in the list. It just puts it as a new client into the list.

How can I avoid the server to save the same client in new client-objects after each connection?

Comment: Can't you just stop calling `socket.connect` multiple times in your client?

Comment: I guess the client checks if the server is available. I don't know if I can stop it

Comment: The client code isn't your own?

Comment: No unfortunately it's not. I'll try to get it though, to see if I can do sth. on the client side. Should I disconnect the connection by the client, after the data are transmitted?

Comment: Well, usually a `socket.io` connection is permanent for the duration of the page view. But if the client is connecting multiple times during the same page view, there's nothing much you can do apart from – if possible – do what @TarekSalah suggests and use sessions to keep track of whether or not a client is already connected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sessionID that come with client to distinguish between different clients. 
If you don't know how to use sessions you can follow this link:
http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/.
 This link explains how to extract session id in sockets using express

Comment: Due to the issues between express and socket.io I don't want to use it. I tried out that example, but it didn't work, although I applied changes for express 3.